# Why is the last return statement not working?

Tags: java, return, bluej

I'm a java-beginner and I can't see where I made a mistake here.

This code is supposed to return the number of letters a word consists of.

Inside method no. 1:
I'm using one variable, to save the number of letters as "int numberOfChar".

Inside method no. 2: 
I simply want to return the value, that I've already saved in Method 1, but when I use this method, all I get back is '0'. Why is that? What did I forget?

```
class Wordlength {

    int numberOfChar;

    /**
     * @param word the word, which length I want to count.
     */
    public int wordlength (String word) {

        int numberOfChar = wort.length();

        return numberOfChar;
    }

    public int giveWordLength() {
        return numberOfChar;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, there are typos everywhere and this code cannot compile... Please read [ask], make a [mcve] and post the correct code.

Comment: Look up "variable shadowing"

Comment: the constructor `public int Wordlength (String word)` should not have a return

Comment: @Blip That's a method, not a constructor

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot that this creates a new local variable, instead of referencing the other one?

```
int numberOfChar = word.length();
```

You can remove `int` from the beginning of the line and it will work, but while you are learning, I would recommend you qualify which variables you are using.

```
this.numberOfChar = word.length();
```

You'll need to fix some other syntax errors, and if this is supposed to be a constructor, then make it one instead of a method. (Constructors don't return)

```
public Wordlength (String word) {
    this.numberOfChar = word.length();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I indeed forgot, that the initial "int" creates a new local variable.

Plus I accidentally made the first method look like a constructor, which I didn't know how to correct, because I didn't find the edit-button. I corrected it by now though.

//Edit:
The code I wrote obviously doesn't make a lot of sense. All I'm doing is playing around with the syntax trying to understand how it works etc. Maybe stack overflow is a wrong address for my rookie-questions.

Comment: Well, you still editted it to be a method instead of a constructor

Comment: And StackOverflow is okay, but not if you post code that can't run.

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted.
This code does run, but I'm using blueJ and not eclipse. I guess that makes the difference.

Comment: I'll test my code with eclipse before I post it here from now on.

Comment: The IDE doesn't make a difference. Your variables do. `wort` is not `word` and you don't have a semicolon on the return statement you asked about. If you are going to change variable names, make sure the code runs after you do that